# Kotlin: Doing math on 1D arrays

Tags: arrays, kotlin, math

In Kotlin, I need to do something like:

`array1 = cos(angle)*array1 + sin(angle)*array2`

1d arrays.

Is that easy?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on exactly what you're asking. But if you wanted, for example, an array that has all the results of an equation from 0 to 359 in degrees, you could do something like this:

```
    val array = DoubleArray(360) { i ->
        val angle = i / 180.0 * PI
        cos(angle) + sin(angle)
    }
```

If you had multiple arrays of the same size, you could use their values in another one:

```
    val array = DoubleArray(360) { i ->
        val angle = i / 180.0 * PI
        cos(angle) * array1[i] + sin(angle) * array2[i]
    }
```

**Edit based on comment:**

If you want to replace values in an existing array:

```
    for (i in array1.indices) {
        val angle = i / 180.0 * PI
        array1[i] = cos(angle) * array1[i] + sin(angle) * array2[i]
    }
```

Comment: I have array1 and array2, same 1d dimensions. I just want to replace values in array1 with an equation of array1 and array2.

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Tenfour04, I am trying your example above (with a correction):

          for (i in 0 until signal.size) {
            val angle = twist / 180.0 * Math.PI
//            signal[i] = Math.cos(angle) * signal[i] + Math.sin(angle) * signal[i]
            signal[i] = signal[i]
          }

But it's giving a compile error:

Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but Float! was expected

That's just the line for signal = signal. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm saying the compiler doesn't like array1[i] = array1[i], for example. Is that wrong syntax??

Comment: Ok, seems I needed to use the set() to reassign a value to an array element.

array.set(newvalue.toFloat(), index)

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin can't do whole-array operations ‘out of the box’, but you can easily do them by defining a few extension functions first.  For example:

```
operator fun Double.times(array: DoubleArray)
    = DoubleArray(array.size){ this * array[it] }

operator fun DoubleArray.plus(other: DoubleArray): DoubleArray {
    require(size == other.size)
    return DoubleArray(size){ this[it] + other[it] }
}
```

That defines overloads for the `+` and `*` operators for `Double`/`DoubleArray` combinations, which lets you write code like:

```
fun main() {
    val array1 = DoubleArray(10){ it.toDouble() }
    val array2 = DoubleArray(10){ it.toDouble() * 2 }

    val array3 = 10.0 * array1 + 20.0 * array2
    println(array3.joinToString())
}
```

You'd probably want to define similar extension functions for multiplication where the scalar comes second, subtraction of arrays, division by a scalar, &c too, but I'm sure you can see how those would work.

The `require()` check gives an `IllegalArgumentException` at run-time if you try to add two arrays of different lengths.  (There's no easy way to check that at compile time.)

(There's a slight gotcha in that there's already a `+` operator for arrays, but it concatenates them instead of doing arithmetic.  Luckily, defining our own here overrides that.)